# Generic class for multiple actions with different member variables

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am trying to define an overall class, call it "Command" which can take an "enum Action" that defines which command to run. I would like to have this class represent any possible command (store each command's variable) but I don't want to define a class per command that inherits from the general Command class.

For example, the class Command defines an "enum Action" that defines which command to run. If it is start, it stores an int and a char*, if it is something like "setResolution", it stores two ints: width and height.

I would like this class to be able to represent any command, but I am not sure what is the best OO way to achieve this please. My OO is very rusty and I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't involve inheritance. Thank you.

Comment: You should look into the *Command pattern* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern.

Comment: Looking into it, thanks!

Comment: don't store a char*, use std::string instead

Comment: doesn't command pattern require inheritance? Not that I see any way to do what you want without inheritance...

Comment: Where do the command arguments come from?

Comment: This class is to be used for Socket transmission (sharing those commands over the network). They are read from an XML file that defines which command to execute, and in which order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe sounds a lot like the combined functionality of using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). Using these creates a callable function object that stores all of the arguments that need to be passed while allowing you to execute the call without knowing any specific details. It works with both member functions and free functions. You could change your `Command` class into a simple wrapper that describes the requirements.

The example below does this using free functions. The `Command` class does not care about the arguments or their types. All it cares about is how the command itself is dispatched.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class Command
{
public:
    Command(const std::string& name, const std::function<void()>& func)
        : name_(name), func_(func) {}

    Command(const Command& o) : name_(o.name_), func_(o.func_) {}

    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "executing " << name_ << std::endl;
        func_();
    };

    const std::string name() const { return name_; }

private:
    Command& operator=(const Command&);

    const std::string           name_;
    const std::function<void()> func_;
};

void start(int a, const char* b)
{
    std::cout << "start(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl;
}
void setResolution(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "setResolution(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Command start("start", std::bind(start, 1, "hello world"));
    Command setRes("setRes", std::bind(setResolution, 640, 480));

    start();
    setRes();
}
```

Comment: If you can do without the getter functions this can basically be simplified to a lambda expression, i.e. `auto command = [] { start(1, "hello world"); }`.